# Can I access Chrome chrome://gpu/ data with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gpu

When I open the page chrome://gpu/ I can see if the video is hardware accelerated or not, can I get that information using Javascript? (I'm building a Chrome extension so maybe there is an API?)

Thx in advance!

Comment: You can't inject scripts into chrome's internal pages.

Comment: I thought that maybe there is some API which I could run from the background process, doesnt seem likely I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`requirements` section](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#requirements) of the manifest:

> Hosting sites such as
>   the Chrome Web Store may use this list to dissuade users from
>   installing apps or extensions that will not work on their computer.
>   Supported requirements currently include "3D" and "plugins";
>   additional requirements checks may be added in the future.

We're also discussing a system-capability API to let individual apps and extensions progressively enhance their behavior according to the runtime environment.

Red John's basic answer in his comment is correct, though: the internal Chrome pages are off-limits.